# Mix two columns in 'between' clause

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I have a table like this :

[image: Table]

I want to get data between Dec 2014 - Feb 2015, which is I should use 2 columns inside between clause : 
`between (month = 12 and year = 2014) and (month = 1 and year = 2015)`

I think it's not possible. 
Is there another way to do this? Really need your suggestion.

Comment: Postgres would allow `where (year, month) between (2014,12) and (2015,2);` maybe MySQL does as well.

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to actually change the table to use real dates if possible. If they're incomplete dates, you can force them to be at the start of the period, such as `yyyy-mm-01`.

Then you can easily use `between` in your queries along with all sorts of wondrous date manipulation functions.

However, if that's not an option, and your data is correct in the sense that only valid data exists in the table, you can just use something like:

```
select * from mytable
where (year = 2014 and month >= 12)
   or (year = 2015 and month <=  2)
```

That can be generalised into a query for date between M1/Y1 and M2/Y2 inclusive, with something like:

```
select * from mytable
where (year = Y1 and month >= M1)
   or (year > Y1 and year < Y2)
   or (year = Y2 and month <= M2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from `table` where (month =12 and year=2014) or (month in (1,2) and year =2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Year*12+Month BETWEEN @StartYear*12+@StartMonth and @EndYear*12+@EndMonth
```

Using your valuews, that would be:

```
Year*12+Month BETWEEN 2014*12+12 and 2015*12+1
```

If there are a lot of records and you are depending on indexing Month and Year, this might be slow.  In that case, you might want to try other optionsAnd see if you get performance improvements

Comment: This will force a full table scan as the database will have to calculate each row's date, resulting in horrible performance even for small tables. Even the edit isn't correct, eg imagine comparing 11/15 to 1/15

Comment: Yes, I noticed the edit mistake just now and removed it.  As for the performance issue, I'm aware of it, which is why I added the update and, now that there are plenty of good solutions, suggested that one of them might work.

Comment: Besides, if you want to generate a date value, just generate a date value with `MAKEDATE`. The result will be a lot easier to understand